# android: how to select other view in onItemClick

Tags: java, android, gridview, onitemclick

I try to create an Android tic-tac-toe application which I use grid view as an arena. This is the game rule:

1. The arena is 3x3 scale that mean 9 box.
2. When I click a box, the cpu player select the other box.
3. The box that have clicked will change its image.

The problem is I only can change my selected view, and I want the CPU player to change his selected view. That mean on one call of `onItemClick`, there must be two views involved and changed its image. How can I do this? Can I change CPU `ImageView` based on position?

This is my code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // my selected view
    ImageView myBox = (ImageView) view;
    myBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybox_img_after_clicked);

    //cpu selected view
    //ImageView cpuBox = ???;
    //cpuBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.cpubox_img_after_clicked);
}
```

Comment: your adapter should bind with an array, so you can change the value inside the array and notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: is there any easier way, like ImageView imageView = (ImageView) xxx.getViewByPosition(position) ?